# Переносимая библиотека классов. Отсутствую директивы

Tags: c#, dll, uwp

Писал консольное приложение и мне захотелось вынести кое-какие файлы в библиотеку (переносимая). И я столкнулся тем, что невозможно найти определения классов, которые в консольном приложении работали нормально. А именно:

- BinaryFormatter
- Aes
- AesCryptoServiceProvider
- CryptoStream
- Serializable

Как подключить эти классы???

P.S. Данную библиотеку предстоит использовать в приложении UWP.

По возможности, приведите альтернативы для UWP.

Выбранные платформы:
[image: 1]

Comment: А что не так, например, с using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary ?

Comment: Не знаю, пишет что отсутствует.

Answer (score 1):

Сериализации, к примеру, нет на платформе XBox 360 - а потому она не попадает в наиболее общую платформу PCL.

Попробуйте сменить платформу в настройках проекта на менее общую.

Comment: Ну это же бред. В том плане, что чем XBox так уникальна что они не смогли в один класс? И они еще утверждают про универсальность приложений! Чем дольше в это углубляюсь тем больше хочу обратно.

Comment: @SanychGoilo для XBox есть отдельная версия CLR. И для Silverlight. И для WP тоже своя CLR. Да, они сами признали что это все - бред, потому и начали проект .NET Core. Но сейчас имеем что имеем.

Comment: И что мне делать? Мне нужны эти классы. Может какие нибудь dll подключить?
Пишешь ты, пишешь, а потом узнаешь, что это все бесполезно.

Comment: @SanychGoilo говорю же, попробуй сменить платформу. У PCL есть аж 5 разновидностей.

Comment: @SanychGoilo как вариант, можно отказаться от идеи переносимой библиотеки вообще, и собирать ее для разных платформ отдельно.

Comment: У меня и так по мнимому. Данных классов нет в UWP.